# Xamarin for Android - Async: using "async" inside an eventhandler in the activity lifecycle goes to the next eventhandler

Tags: xamarin, async-await, xamarin.android

When we do await for something inside an eventhandler in the activity lifecycle, goes to the next event handler when doing the "async" part.

We are doing things inside OnCreate (or OnStart), some of them take time. So we use async in order to make the app responsive during this time. 
But when we do this it jumps to the OnResume part.

While it does complete all the jobs it was required to do, It's not the way we need it to happen. We can't make the OnResume happen before OnCreate finishes

Should we do this in a different way?

Comment: Can you explain better what you are trying to achieve? In activity life cycle you have OnCreate -> OnStart -> OnResume. When one finishes other starts.That is how activity works and you can't change that.

Comment: I know the lifecycle.
The problem is that OnResume runs before OnCreate ends...

Comment: Can you post example code of what you are doing. OnResume will never be called if OnCreate is not finished.

Comment: @HagaiL - I am having the exact same problem! Did you find the reason?

Comment: @StevanMladenovic - I also thought that the lifecycle is fixed but OnResume gets called before OnCreate fully ends. I believe it is because async / await that I have used within OnCreate. It seems that as soon as the execution reaches the "async" part, OnCreate halts and starts waiting whereas OnResume gets called!! Can you help?

Comment: Basically async await is just syntactic sugar. So when you do use await inside the OnCreate on create will return and when it returns OnResume will start. There is no way around it if you want to have async operation in OnCreate. If the OnResume waits for async operation in OnCreate then its the same as you doing it synchronously.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of async-xamarin.  The base `Activity` class code does not await the life-cycle methods and so yes, the `OnStart()` and `OnResume()` methods will be called while an awaited call in `OnCreate()` is running.  The easiest way is to keep all code within a single life-cycle method

```
public class MyActivity : Activity
{
    private Data data;
    public async void OnCreate()
    {
        data = await getDataFromServerAsync();
        calculateValues(data);
        showValues(data);
    }
}
```

If you need to split the code across methods, you need to get creative.  For example, if you need to load data from a server only when the activity launches, but every time a activity resumes it needs to update the display using local data as well, you could check that all required preprocesses have been done:

```
public class MyActivity : Activity
{
    private Data data;
    public async void OnCreate()
    {
        data = await getDataFromServerAsync();
        await calculateValuesIncludingLocalData(data); 
        showValues(data);
    }
    public void OnResume()
    {
        if(data != null)
        { 
            await calculateValuesIncludingLocalData(data);
            showValues(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Note there will be issues when stepping through this code as the `async` method in `OnCreate()` could easily complete before you get to step through the `OnResume()` method.